# How to select one input from a multi-select input on Ctrl+left button click?

Tags: jquery, html

I got multi-select HTML input, I want to single select on Ctrl + left mouse button click or disable Ctrl-click functionality. How do i achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/dct1x25v/3/

```
<select multiple="" id="MySelect">
  <option>I am Option 1</option>
  <option>I am Option 2</option>
  <option>I am Option 3</option>
  <option>I am Option 4</option>
  <option>I am Option 5</option>
  <option>I am Option 6</option>
  <option>I am Option 7</option>
  <option>I am Option 8</option>
  <option>I am Option 9</option>
</select>
```

Already tried:

```
$('#MySelect').bind("mousedown", function (e) {
  // alert(event.keycode)
  e.metaKey = false;
}).selectable()

$(#MySelect).keydown(function(event){
  if(event.which=="17")
    cntrlIsPressed = true;
  alert(event.which)
});
```

Didn't work.

Comment: the selector should have quotes around it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this disable `ctrl` + `click`;

```
$('#MySelect').mousedown(function(e)
{  
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        return false;
    }  
});
```